# Problem discussed in Relation in Set Theory

Tags: relations

I am reading a book Axioms and Set Theory - A first course in Set Theory by Robert Andr´e

In the book an example if discussed regarding composition of two relations `R` and `T`

For a set `S`

`S = {a,b,c,{a},{a,b},{{c}},∅,{∅}}`

The relations `R` and `T` on `S` are given as

`R = {(x, y) : x ∈ y}`

`T = {(x, y) : x = {y}}`

So now,

`R = { (a, {a}), (a, {a, b}), (b, {a, b}), (∅, {∅}) }`

`T = { ({a}, a}), ({∅},∅})}`

We define `T∘R`

`T∘R = {(x, y) : (z, y) ∈ T for some z ∈ imR}`

For the relation `T∘R` we obtain:

`T∘R = {(a, a), (∅,∅)}`

For the relation `R∘T` we obtain:

`R∘T = {({a}, {a}), ({∅}, {∅})}`

But I am getting my answer as:

`R∘T = {({a}, {a}), ({a}, {a, b}), ({∅}, {∅})}`

Am I making any mistake or the example discussed in book has the error

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your mathematics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your definition of $T\circ R$ needs a bit of work, it should read

$$
T\circ R = \{(x,y)\mid \text{there exists $z$ such that }(x,z)\in R\text{ and }(z,y)\in T\}
$$

Note: it matters which $x$ the $z$ comes from in the relation $R$.

---

Other than that, I would agree with your answer: $(\{a\},\{a,b\})$ should be in $R\circ T$ since we have $(\{a\},a)\in T$ and $(a,\{a,b\})\in R$.